# Getting reply to bump post in JComments, factoring in another query

Tags: extensions

I'm posting this in hopes someone is familiar with the variables and objects and all of that in different sections of JComments.

I use a query in tpl_tree.php to get the date of the last reply made in the thread and that displays on the top level. There may be a better way to write it, but i'm very new to php and databases, and it displays what i need it to correctly.

```
if ($comment->children == 0) {
echo JCommentsText::formatDate($comment->date, JText::_('D M j Y g:ia')); 
} else { 

   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
   $db->setQuery('SELECT thread_id, date 
                  FROM #__jcomments
                  WHERE thread_id = ' . $comment->id . '
                  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1');
   $db->loadAssocList();

   $row = $db->loadAssocList(); 

   foreach ($row as $item) { 
      echo JHtml::_('date', $item[date], JText::_('D M j Y g:ia')); 
   } 
} ?>
```

Now the problem seems to be how to get that date to replace the parent = 0 comment date in the order. I can't seem to figure out the syntax to use to perform this query because the ->children doesn't work where the orderby code is set and then have it use that date in place of the parent date when reply cases come up.

The order by is set in jcomments settings in administration, but factoring in replies isn't an option in settings, so code to alter is **components/com_jcomments/models/jcomments.php** There are 3 references to the order the comments are listed in, the first at the top

```
if (!isset($options['orderBy'])) {
            $options['orderBy'] = self::_getDefaultOrder();
        }
```

the second is the case in the query where it sets parent = 0 comments as threaddate:

```
. "\n,
     case 
       when c.parent = 0 
       then unix_timestamp(c.date)
       else 0 
     end as threaddate"
```

and the third is the function that feeds the admin setting result to the top code:

```
if ($config->get('template_view') == 'tree') {
            switch($config->getInt('comments_tree_order')) {
                case 2:
                    $result = 'threadDate DESC, c.date ASC';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $result = 'c.parent, c.date DESC';
                    break;
                default:
                    $result = 'c.parent, c.date ASC';
                    break;
            }
```

Case 2 being the orderby the comments are currently set at. I've tried adding cases to the query, but can't seem to find the right wording or syntax to have it look at thread_id and if it matches parent = 0's id then get the most recent date of all of those matches as threaddate to put into the order. Or maybe someone sees a better way to do this extra check in one of the other areas? I've tried pretty much everything i can think of and haven't been able to work it in yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Database sample, database names have been changed and emails are all my testing account emails. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4pqz9MFGGaQ1ucB3nmw1De/0

This is the whole query from components/com_jcomments/models/jcomments.php

```
$query = "SELECT c.id, c.parent, c.object_id, c.object_group, c.userid, c.name, c.username, c.title, c.comment"
        . "\n, c.email, c.homepage, c.date, c.date as datetime, c.ip, c.published, c.deleted, c.checked_out, c.checked_out_time"
        . "\n, c.isgood, c.ispoor"
        . ($votes ? "\n, v.value as voted" : "\n, 1 as voted")
        . "\n, case when c.parent = 0 then unix_timestamp(c.date) else 0 end as threaddate"
        . ($objectinfo ? "\n, jo.title AS object_title, jo.link AS object_link, jo.access AS object_access" : ", '' AS object_title, '' AS object_link, 0 AS object_access, 0 AS object_owner")
        . "\nFROM #__jcomments AS c"
        . ($votes ? "\nLEFT JOIN #__jcomments_votes AS v ON c.id = v.commentid " . ($acl->getUserId() ? " AND  v.userid = " . $acl->getUserId() : " AND v.userid = 0 AND v.ip = '" . $acl->getUserIP() . "'") : "")
        . ($objectinfo ? "\n LEFT JOIN #__jcomments_objects AS jo ON jo.object_id = c.object_id AND jo.object_group = c.object_group AND jo.lang=c.lang" : "")
        . (count($where) ? ("\nWHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where)) : "")
        . "\nORDER BY " . $orderBy
        . (($limit > 0) ? "\nLIMIT $limitStart, $limit" : "");

    return $query;
```

Comment: I wish i could, have never done that before and i'm not sure how. Might be some time to figure it out.

Comment: It is as easy as going into your phpMyAdmin doing an Export, then dumping the CREATE and INSERT INTO queries into the left side panel, then submit.  That will create a url for me to look at.  (I'm working at the moment, so I'll have to look after work).  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333953/2943403

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eJBZ930  Once you have dumped everything into text  copy past into sqlfiddle (then remove anything unnecessary / private) then build that schema.  That will create the new url for us).

Comment: Hopefully this is it, sqlfiddle wouldn't load for me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4pqz9MFGGaQ1ucB3nmw1De/0

Comment: The problem that's come up is it only bumps the thread when a comment is made to the original post, replies to replies dates display in tree template but don't get added to the order.

Comment: Hmm.  So are we talking about isolating data to a finite length, or is the depth variable?  We don't need recursion, right?  From your sample data, can you express which row has an undesirable `threaddate`?  I am at work again, so I can't dive in right now.

Comment: This is why i was using thread_id in my query above, all children have the thread_id of the parent = 0 comment id, the parent = 0 comment has a thread_id of 0 though. Also the reply order has shifted from ASC to DESC under the parent=0 comments.

Comment: Yes i think that's got it. You're pretty good at this stuff. Just have to remember to add thread_id to the initial selection above that part of the code as c.thread_id. The alternate order of replies isn't that big of a deal, some already have them set that way. I may mess with that a bit to see if i can get those asc again, but other than that i'm happy to get this far. Thanks again.

Comment: I always _try_ to keep comments on the page to a minimum - that's why I've deleted a few already.  Please take a moment to delete any comments that do not contain content that will be useful to future readers -- researchers don't like to wade through lots of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note, that any hacking to the extensions files have the potential to be overwritten when an extension upgrade is performed.

As a pure mysql solution, you only need to write a subquery into the `$query` @ **components/com_jcomments/models/jcomments.php** inside of `function _getCommentsQuery()`.

The subquery will effectively assign a parent with the max (latest) date of itself and all of its children based on the `thread_id` data.

Because the conditional outcome on this condition in the SELECT clause is binary, an `IF` expression is better suited versus a verbose `CASE` expression.

```
. "\n, IF(c.thread_id = 0, (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tsp_jcomments WHERE thread_id = c.id OR id = c.id), c.date) AS threaddate"
```

> UPDATE: After feedback from @Mythic, the desired order dictates that the `else` value be `0`, like this:
>
> ```
> "\n, IF(c.parent = 0, (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tsp_jcomments WHERE thread_id = c.id OR id = c.id), 0) AS threaddate
> ```

The logic says:

- if `thread_id` is `0` (meaning the row is a parent)

  - then find the latest date value from the same table (as a new set of data) so long as the new row's `thread_id` value is the original row's `id` value or if the new row's `id` value is the original row's `id`.
- otherwise, (meaning the row is not a parent)

  - use the row's `date` column value.

Here is a demonstration of the solution on your sample data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4pqz9MFGGaQ1ucB3nmw1De/4

Here is a visual representation of how the assignment works:

```
||    [logic]             threaddate      | id  | thread_id |       date                
|| ---------------- | ------------------- | --- | --------- | ------------------- 
|| MAX() from 70 -> | 2018-10-18 18:21:58 | 1   | 0         | 2018-07-21 08:04:04 
|| self ->          | 2018-07-24 22:00:26 | 3   | 1         | 2018-07-24 22:00:26 
|| self ->          | 2018-07-24 22:07:59 | 4   | 1         | 2018-07-24 22:07:59 
|| self ->          | 2018-07-29 02:25:02 | 5   | 0         | 2018-07-29 02:25:02 
|| MAX() from 80 -> | 2018-10-20 15:42:41 | 9   | 0         | 2018-07-29 11:43:00 
|| self ->          | 2018-08-07 11:29:05 | 11  | 1         | 2018-08-07 11:29:05 
|| self ->          | 2018-08-19 01:59:46 | 13  | 0         | 2018-08-19 01:59:46 
|| self ->          | 2018-08-20 05:10:22 | 14  | 0         | 2018-08-20 05:10:22 
|| MAX() from 96 -> | 2018-10-28 23:05:59 | 15  | 0         | 2018-09-10 09:16:31 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-10 11:03:08 | 16  | 15        | 2018-09-10 11:03:08 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-10 13:01:59 | 17  | 1         | 2018-09-10 13:01:59 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-12 05:14:56 | 18  | 15        | 2018-09-12 05:14:56 
|| MAX() from 62 -> | 2018-10-10 20:19:25 | 19  | 0         | 2018-09-13 21:43:02 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-13 21:45:25 | 20  | 19        | 2018-09-13 21:45:25 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-13 21:50:27 | 21  | 19        | 2018-09-13 21:50:27 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-13 21:55:03 | 22  | 19        | 2018-09-13 21:55:03 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-13 22:32:04 | 23  | 1         | 2018-09-13 22:32:04 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-14 01:50:59 | 24  | 1         | 2018-09-14 01:50:59 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-14 01:51:53 | 25  | 1         | 2018-09-14 01:51:53 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-14 01:52:42 | 26  | 1         | 2018-09-14 01:52:42 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-14 01:54:22 | 27  | 1         | 2018-09-14 01:54:22 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-14 01:55:36 | 28  | 1         | 2018-09-14 01:55:36 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-14 01:57:33 | 29  | 1         | 2018-09-14 01:57:33 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-14 01:59:30 | 30  | 1         | 2018-09-14 01:59:30 
|| self ->          | 2018-09-16 22:50:29 | 31  | 1         | 2018-09-16 22:50:29 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 05:14:01 | 33  | 1         | 2018-10-07 05:14:01 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:31:46 | 34  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:31:46 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:32:44 | 35  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:32:44 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:33:17 | 36  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:33:17 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:34:06 | 37  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:34:06 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:34:41 | 38  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:34:41 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:35:21 | 39  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:35:21 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:35:59 | 40  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:35:59 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-07 11:36:44 | 41  | 0         | 2018-10-07 11:36:44 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:24:22 | 42  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:24:22 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:25:03 | 43  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:25:03 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:25:41 | 44  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:25:41 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:26:42 | 45  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:26:42 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:27:29 | 46  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:27:29 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:28:07 | 47  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:28:07 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:28:58 | 48  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:28:58 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:29:44 | 49  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:29:44 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:32:02 | 50  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:32:02 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:33:34 | 51  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:33:34 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:34:10 | 52  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:34:10 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:34:58 | 53  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:34:58 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:35:57 | 54  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:35:57 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:36:28 | 55  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:36:28 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:37:30 | 56  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:37:30 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:38:01 | 57  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:38:01 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:38:43 | 58  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:38:43 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-09 11:39:17 | 59  | 0         | 2018-10-09 11:39:17 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-10 19:23:52 | 60  | 19        | 2018-10-10 19:23:52 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-10 19:56:09 | 61  | 19        | 2018-10-10 19:56:09 
|| MAX() for 19 ->  | 2018-10-10 20:19:25 | 62  | 19        | 2018-10-10 20:19:25 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-13 21:53:45 | 63  | 0         | 2018-10-13 21:53:45 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-13 21:58:35 | 64  | 0         | 2018-10-13 21:58:35 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-13 22:16:41 | 65  | 0         | 2018-10-13 22:16:41 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-15 05:37:36 | 66  | 1         | 2018-10-15 05:37:36 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-15 06:51:10 | 67  | 1         | 2018-10-15 06:51:10 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-18 18:02:31 | 68  | 1         | 2018-10-18 18:02:31 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-18 18:03:26 | 69  | 1         | 2018-10-18 18:03:26 
|| MAX() for 1 ->   | 2018-10-18 18:21:58 | 70  | 1         | 2018-10-18 18:21:58 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 07:46:00 | 71  | 15        | 2018-10-20 07:46:00 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 08:16:58 | 72  | 15        | 2018-10-20 08:16:58 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 15:01:07 | 73  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:01:07 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 15:04:49 | 74  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:04:49 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 15:05:58 | 75  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:05:58 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 15:40:11 | 76  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:40:11 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 15:40:49 | 77  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:40:49 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 15:41:22 | 78  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:41:22 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-20 15:42:11 | 79  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:42:11 
|| MAX() for 9 ->   | 2018-10-20 15:42:41 | 80  | 9         | 2018-10-20 15:42:41 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-21 01:37:22 | 81  | 15        | 2018-10-21 01:37:22 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-22 15:19:45 | 82  | 0         | 2018-10-22 15:19:45 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-23 21:30:41 | 83  | 0         | 2018-10-23 21:30:41 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:46:26 | 84  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:46:26 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:47:13 | 85  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:47:13 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:48:03 | 86  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:48:03 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:48:37 | 87  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:48:37 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:50:01 | 88  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:50:01 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:50:31 | 89  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:50:31 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:51:18 | 90  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:51:18 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:51:50 | 91  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:51:50 
|| self ->          | 2018-10-25 13:52:23 | 92  | 0         | 2018-10-25 13:52:23 
|| MAX() for 15 ->  | 2018-10-28 23:05:59 | 96  | 15        | 2018-10-28 23:05:59
```

This is just one way to solve the issue.  I am certain that there could be multiple ways to fix this issue.

p.s. After taking a look under the hood, I don't like some of the coding practices/styling in the extension.  It doesn't use Joomla's query building methods, it uses the `@` ([error-control/stfu operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)) which is mostly frowned upon, and the queries themselves could be written more eloquently.

Comment: I actually got the reply dates to go back to asc order (instead of desc) by adding the case back in if anyone is interested **. "\n, 
                                   case when c.parent = 0 then
        IF(
        c.thread_id = 0,
        (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tsp_jcomments WHERE thread_id = c.id OR id = c.id),
        unix_timestamp(c.date)
    ) else 0 
    end AS threaddate,
    c.id,
    c.parent,
    c.date"**

Comment: Because there are no cases (in your sample data) where `parent` DOES EQUAL `0` and `thread_id` DOES NOT EQUAL `0` (In other words, when one is `0` so is the other)... I believe you can safely use this simpler condition: `IF (c.parent = 0, (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tsp_jcomments WHERE thread_id = c.id OR id = c.id), 0)`  Please test and confirm my assertion.

Comment: Yes, does it as well. Simpler.